# Logical expressions with variables to select subset in R error: subset must be logical

Tags: r, subset, logical-operators

I am trying to select a subset in R based on logical expressions, including 3 different variables. Specifically, I want to select a subset for each `group` when `t >= ts` and `t <= te` (basically, when t E [ts,te]).

Example data:

```
t <- c(1,2,3,4,5,-1,2,3,4,5,6)
ts<- c(2,2,2,2,2,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1)
te <- c(4,4,4,4,4,5,5,5,5,5,5)
group <-c(1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2)
v<-c(1,2,4,5,1,1,3,2,4,4,1)
dt <- data.frame(cbind(t,ts,te,group,v))
```

Desired output:

```
t <- c(2,3,4,-1,2,3,4,5)
ts<- c(2,2,2,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1)
te <- c(4,4,4,5,5,5,5,5)
group <-c(1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2)
v<-c(2,4,5,1,3,2,4,4)
dt1 <- data.frame(cbind(t,ts,te,group,v))
```

I tried:

```
dt1<-dt %>%
  group_by(group) %>% subset(dt, "t" >= "ts" & "t" <= "te")
```

But I got the error:

> Error in subset.data.frame(., dt, "t" >= "ts" & "t" <= "te") :
> 'subset' must be logical

I also tried the solution I saw in some posts here:

```
criteria <- c("t >= ts", "t <= te")

dt1<-dt %>%
  group_by(group) %>% subset(dt, eval(parse(text = criteria)))
```

But I still get:

> Error in subset.data.frame(., dt, eval(parse(text = criteria))) :
> 'subset' must be logical

Any ideas what might me wrong? Many thanks

Comment: If you wish to use `dplyr` try `filter(dt, t >= ts & t <= te)`...looks like same as desired output. `filter` allows you to subset rows using column values.

Answer (score 1):

This should bring your desired output:

```
# your dataframe

t <- c(1,2,3,4,5,-1,2,3,4,5,6)
ts<- c(2,2,2,2,2,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1)
te <- c(4,4,4,4,4,5,5,5,5,5,5)
group <-c(1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2)
v<-c(1,2,4,5,1,1,3,2,4,4,1)
dt <- data.frame(cbind(t,ts,te,group,v))

# your desired output

desired_output <- subset(dt, t >= ts & t <= te)


Edit: as Ben suggested: if you want to make it with dplyr use filter

desired_output<-dt %>%
  group_by(group) %>% 
  filter(t >= ts & t <= te)
```

Comment: Hi, thanks a lot for your reply. I tried your answer, including the group function : dt1<-dt %>%
  group_by(group) %>% subset(dt, rt >= ts & t <= te), but I keep getting the same error..

Comment: Thank you both! I ran it and it gives the same output. however, I tried it on a different dataset (with more negative values) and it seems like it considers only absolute values